# Extract float from csv python

Tags: python, csv, floating-point

I have a csv file like this (name,floatNumber):

```
quirrell,0,000281885
flamel,0,000175286
quirrells,0,000154252
```

I would like to get from it all the float numbers.

```
for filename in os.listdir('output'):
    with open("output/"+filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in readCSV:
            print(row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

Using `delimiter=','`, I have this output

```
quirrell 0 000281885
flamel 0 000175286
quirrells 0 000154252
```

where the number is splitted.
How can I get this output and put all the float inside some variables?

```
quirrell, 0,000281885
flamel 0,000175286
quirrells 0,000154252
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might find it easier not to use the CSV library:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        name, value = row.strip().split(',', 1)
        value = float(value.replace(',', '.'))
        print(name, value)
```

This would display:

```
quirrell 0.000281885
flamel 0.000175286
quirrells 0.000154252
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a float after joining the string objects

**Ex:**

```
print(row[0],float(".".join([row[1],row[2]])))
```